# Cannot catch the UnrecognizedPropertyException with ExpectedException using JUnit 4.11

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit4, expected-exception

I wrote the following code :

```
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void testMappingException() {


        exception.expect(ArithmeticException.class);

        int x = 1 / 0;
    }
```

Everything works correctly. Unfortunatelly it is not working correctly in this case:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
void add(String json) {

    try {

        X x = mapper.readValue(json, X.class); // exception here

    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

========================================================

```
@Before
public void setUpBeforeClass() {
    jsonTestExcpetion = "{\"aaa\" : \"bbb\"}";
}


@Test
public void testMappingException() {

    MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    exception.expect(UnrecognizedPropertyException.class);
    myClass.add(jsonTestExcpetion);

}
```

It should catch the exception

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException

but in fact, exception is thrown normally and tests fails.

Have you got any ideas?

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you call exception.expect(ArithmeticException.class) in the second test?

Comment: Could you please add the code of myClass.add

Comment: I added body of this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is catched inside `add(String)`. Therefore JUnit doesn't see it and cannot test it. (JUnit sees only exceptions that are thrown by the `add` method.)

How to test it? There is only one side effect of this method that leaks outside of the method: it writes something to `System.err`. You can test this using the [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules) library.

But, usually it is bad practice to silently catch exceptions. The caller does not know that an exception occured. I suggest to not catching the exceptions:

```
void add(String json) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    X x = mapper.readValue(json, X.class);
    return null;
}
```

Then your test will work.

You can wrap the exceptions with a runtime exception, if you don't like the `throws` in the method's signature.

```
void add(String json) {
  try {
    X x = mapper.readValue(json, X.class);
    return null;
  } catch (JsonParseException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems strange that I need to change my code to test it. I want to keep it in this shape and write test. Seriously, it is not possible?

Comment: As I told before. Your code writes to System.err and you can test this using the System Rules library. Should I add an example?

Comment: Sorry, I focused on another part of your message. I will try it.